# C++ arithmetic on time intervals

Tags: c++, boost-date-time, boost-icl

I already have working (ugly) code for this, but I will ask anyway:

I have the time intervals [09:15, 10:00), [21:10, 21:45) during weekdays. Given time `t` and a number of seconds `s`, if `t` is within the intervals, I have to calculate the date and time where `t - s` would fall into.

- Example: t = 20130913 21:15, s = 600, t - s falls into 20130913 09:55.
- Example: t = 20130923 09:16, s = 120, t - s falls into 20130920 21:44.

Is there a way of doing this in C++ cleanly (boost::icl? boost::date_time?)

I have tried boost::icl, it can certainly hold the time ranges in an `interval_set<Time>` and find which interval a certain `Time` is in, but if `t - s` time point does not fall into an interval range, I don't see how I can find the nearest interval before that time point, and how to detect if I have to go back a day or through the whole weekend.

Comment: What would the result be for `t = 20130915 21:15` and `s = 3300` (55 min)?  I suspect `20130914 21:40`.  Right?  Also, are these two the only intervals that you have, or is it in general a list of intervals?

Comment: @nickie currently, there are just two intervals within each weekday. Of course clean code would allow more. I forgot to skip weekend in the example (15th was sunday). Examples updated. If 15th was a weekday, your example would have been correct.

Comment: In my code, I sum the seconds for all intervals, then do some ugly calculation to find out how many of which intervals I skipped, then calculate the number of days I need to go back, then find out how many weekends I had to skip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is too complicated to allow for a *clean* solution, at least according to my definition of "clean".

You'll need a container for your (non-overlapping) daily intervals, supporting efficiently the following operations:

- find in which specific interval a given time belongs,
- move an interval backwards, in the container, and
- move to the last interval (in chronological order).

It seems to me that `boost::icl::interval_set<Time>` is an adequate solution.  Your time does not need to keep track of the date, you can have that separately.

Your algorithm will be something like:

```
let d and t be the date and time portions of your t
let i be the interval where t belongs
loop
   if t-s belongs in i then
      return t-s on day d
   else
      let j be the previous interval from i
      if j does not exist (because i was the first) then
         let j be the last interval
         move d one weekday backwards
      s := s - (t-start(i))
      t := end(j)
      i := j
```

This is more or less what you say that your code does.  I don't think it can be much cleaner.

Comment: This is a very good summary of how to do the job iteratively. I'm currently considering treating intervals that lay outside as real intervals